# How to tie together gestures and animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm as beginner as you can get when it comes to iOS animation.
I know you can do fixed (non-gesture-controlled) animations, where you animate a property of a view over a fixed period of time.   This however is entirely different than using a gesture to control the animation.

You know how you fold a sheet of 8x11 paper to put it in an envelope and mail it... you fold it in thirds.  Well basically, my boss wants an interface such that 2/3rds of it is shown on the screen at a time, and the other third is slid on/off screen with a gesture.  So basically, the screen would show either thirds 1 and 2, or thirds 2 and 3 depending on whether you swipe left or right.

Now this also means doing things like snapping/rubberbanding, bouncing, acceleration/deceleration, sticky.  I have no clue where to even start to do something like this.  I'm assuming those types of motions are not already built into any of the iOS framework and if you want snapping/rubberbanding, bouncing, acceleration/deceleration, you'd have to program that entirely from scratch.

Like how would a view know my artificial snap/bounce points are, and sticky behavior, such that you remove your finger from the screen before an arbitrary position is reached, and the view bounces back to it's previous position.

Where would you suggest I start on researching how to drive animations with gestures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at Core Animation. You can do some really complex animations including accelerations, deceleration, bounce and others.

You could easily create a [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html) to track when someone has dragged their finger across the screen. Attach an action `wasDragged` to your gestureRecognizer

From the documentation:

> A panning gesture is continuous. It begins (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when the minimum number of fingers allowed (minimumNumberOfTouches) has moved enough to be considered a pan. It changes (UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) when a finger moves while at least the minimum number of fingers are pressed down. It ends (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when all fingers are lifted.

In `wasDragged` check what state the gestureRecognizer is in. If state is UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged, then you can adjust the size or position of your UIView so that it appears like you are dragging it out. If state is UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded, check whether the point at which the gesture ended is greater than your threshold point (e.g. halfway across the screen). If it isn't, then snap the view back using an animation, if it is then snap the view into where you want it.

Hope this makes sense.